# Is there a HTTP Header to prevent a page from being rendered in anything but an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I am aware of HTTP header settings to prevent a HTML page from being opened inside an IFRAME in a page from another domain, or totally denied in an IFRAME, but is there a HTTP header setting that will prevent the browser page from being rendered directly (i.e. typing the url into the address bar), but Ok in an IFRAME. Needs to work in IE/Chrome/FF etc.

Obviously, I can do this via JS code after the page has been rendered, but I'd like to do this before, or trigger something in the browser, so no code gets into the browser's debugger.

Alternatively, is there something on incoming HTTP request that could be used?

Comment: No, X-Frame does not support this.  You could not do it on the server as the agent sends nothing in the request to indicate where its going to render the page.  You need code within the page itself to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing. `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` and CSP [`Frame-Ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors) cannot enforce that a page is framed.

JavaScript is your friend here. If you include and run the JavaScript at the start of your page, you can detect if it is framed before rendering the rest of the page.

Alternatively, you could set a session variable on an initial page that checks for the outer frame, then redirect, and then check the session variable on this page. This will ensure that the user has navigated there from the first page, although if they then proceed to open it in a new tab or window the session variable will still be set, so you can't force them. Also, this won't work if the user has disabled 3rd party cookies (although you could pass a value in the query-string which is then checked server-side).